# In R, is there a way to change the structure of data so that the identifiers are column titles?

Tags: r

Currently my data set looks like this.

```
     1/1/2020 1/2/2020 1/3/2020 ...
A     Value    Value    Value
B     Value    Value    Value     
C     Value    Value    Value
D     Value    Value    Value
E     Value    Value    Value
F     Value    Value    Value
.
.
.
```

I would like it to look like this.

```
  Time   Letter  Variable
1/1/2020   A       Value
1/1/2020   B       Value
1/1/2020   C       Value
.          .         .
.          .         .
.          .         .
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please include some sample data or use data that ships with an R package as part of your question?  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is reshaping data. Here a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Reshape data
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Var) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  name       A     B     C     D     E     F    
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 01.01.2020 Value Value Value Value Value Value
2 01.02.2020 Value Value Value Value Value Value
3 01.03.2020 Value Value Value Value Value Value
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), `01.01.2020` = c("Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value"), `01.02.2020` = c("Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value"), `01.03.2020` = c("Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", "Value")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

If only long format is required you can use next code (credits to @r2evans) and the function `rownames_to_column()` from `tibble` package:

```
#Code
df %>% rownames_to_column('Var') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Var)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
   Var   name       value
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>
 1 A     01.01.2020 Value
 2 A     01.02.2020 Value
 3 A     01.03.2020 Value
 4 B     01.01.2020 Value
 5 B     01.02.2020 Value
 6 B     01.03.2020 Value
 7 C     01.01.2020 Value
 8 C     01.02.2020 Value
 9 C     01.03.2020 Value
10 D     01.01.2020 Value
11 D     01.02.2020 Value
12 D     01.03.2020 Value
13 E     01.01.2020 Value
14 E     01.02.2020 Value
15 E     01.03.2020 Value
16 F     01.01.2020 Value
17 F     01.02.2020 Value
18 F     01.03.2020 Value
```

Data used for last part is:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(`01.01.2020` = c("Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value"), `01.02.2020` = c("Value", "Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value"), `01.03.2020` = c("Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value", "Value")), row.names = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: (1) I think `A`,`B`,... were row names and possibly not a column; and (2) I think the OP asked for the longer version, no need for `pivot_wider`? (The question title might be confusing one of us.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes you are right! I will update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transpose` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'Var')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(`01.01.2020` = c("Value", "Value", "Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value"), `01.02.2020` = c("Value", "Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value"), `01.03.2020` = c("Value", "Value", 
"Value", "Value", "Value", "Value")), row.names = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame")
```